# Detectar se está dentro de callback?

Tags: javascript, scope

Basicamente quero que uma função se comporte diferente se tiver dentro de um callback. Veja o exemplo:

```
import Test from './test ;'

Test.say('Olá!'); // Deve imprimir: "Olá!"

Test.group(() => {
  Test.say('Ei!'); // Deve imprimir: "Ei! - Dentro do grupo."

  Test.say('Ei, como vai?'); // Deve imprimir: "Ei, como vai? - Dentro do grupo."
});

Test.say('Olá, como vai?'); // Deve imprimir: "Olá, como vai?"
```

Aquivo `test.js`:

```
export default class Test {
  say(word) {
    // Se estiver dentro do grupo:
    if (estiverDentroDoGrupo) {
      return console.log(`${word} - Dentro do grupo.`);
    }

    console.log(word);
  }

  group(callback) {
    callback();
  }
}
```

Comment: O fato de você precisar disso é sinal de um problema de arquitetura da sua aplicação. As "soluções" envolvem gambiarras e o resultado é um maior acoplamento no seu código. Eu repensaria a necessidade disso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro, tem que ser dito que mágica não existe. E as possibilidades de uma solução são tantas quanto a imaginação permitir.

Onde não tenha concorrência e assíncronia, uma solução que você não precise alterar o main.js pode ser essa:

```
let inGroup = false;

export default class Test{
  say(word) {
    // Se estiver dentro do grupo:
    if (inGroup) {
      return console.log(`${word} - Dentro do grupo.`);
    }

    console.log(word);
  },

  group(callback) {
    inGroup = true;
    callback();
    inGroup = false;
  }
}
```

Outras opções envolvem obter o nome da função que chamou `say`, emulando o que `arguments.calle.caller` faziam no JS antigos.

main js

```
const Test = require('./test');

Test.say('Olá!'); // Deve imprimir: "Olá!"

Test.group(function() {
  Test.groupSay('Ei!'); // Deve imprimir: "Ei! - Dentro do grupo."

  Test.groupSay('Ei, como vai?'); // Deve imprimir: "Ei, como vai? - Dentro do grupo."
});

Test.say('Olá, como vai?'); // Deve imprimir: "Olá, como vai?"
```

test.js

```
module.exports = {
  say,

  groupSay() {
    return say.apply({ inGroup: true }, arguments);
  },

  group(callback) {
    setTimeout(callback, 100);
  }
}

function say(word) {
  // Se estiver dentro do grupo:
  if (this.inGroup) {
    return console.log(`${word} - Dentro do grupo.`);
  }

  console.log(word);
}
```

Comment: E se for assíncrono?

Comment: vou adicionar outro exemplo